# How can i load multiple audio files in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, load, wav

I have a Matlab project.I have to create a Neural Network and I have to train it to recognize digits (0-9) ..
For that reason I want to import 1520 .wav files for random people saying that digits..How can I import all 1520 wav files ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I would imagine you should process the files one at a time, not import them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

The code below could scan the current dir and read all the `.wav` files into a Cell array, but if your files are named with some rules, e.g. something like `sound1.wav` & `sound2.wav`, you could just generate a Cell array which denotes the name of every file, and read them by a single loop.

```
clc; clear;
%Scan all the files in the current library
S=dir;
%Search for .wav files and read them
p=1;
WavY={};
WavFs={};
for ii=1:length(S)
  if (~isempty(findstr('.wav',S(ii).name)) && (S(ii).isdir == 0)) 
    [WavY{p},WavFs{p}]=audioread(S(ii).name);  
    p=p+1;
  end
end
```

Comment: When i run this i take this error: Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.

Error in test_foni (line 9)
  if (~isempty(strfind('.wav',S(ii).name)) && (S(ii).isdir == 0))

Comment: I have tried other way and i get again this message "Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object"

Comment: But nothing pop-up on my Matlab2015b, there must be slightly version difference somewhere, and such an error message denotes that your Matlab taught that you had called some cell arrays in a wrong way, unfortunately. Would you be kind enough to figure out which line cause the error, please?